# React: convert Material-UI function to a react class

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

I'd like to understand how can I convert in React a Material-UI function to a class
From the Material-UI I faced with this code.
Could you please help me to convert to a class ?

https://material-ui.com/components/pickers/

```
import 'date-fns';
import React from 'react';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns';
import {
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
  KeyboardTimePicker,
  KeyboardDatePicker,
} from '@material-ui/pickers';

export default function MaterialUIPickers() {
  // The first commit of Material-UI
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = React.useState(new Date('2014-08-18T21:11:54'));

  const handleDateChange = (date) => {
    setSelectedDate(date);
  };

  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
      <Grid container justify="space-around">
        <KeyboardDatePicker
          disableToolbar
          variant="inline"
          format="MM/dd/yyyy"
          margin="normal"
          id="date-picker-inline"
          label="Date picker inline"
          value={selectedDate}
          onChange={handleDateChange}
          KeyboardButtonProps={{
            'aria-label': 'change date',
          }}
        />

        <KeyboardTimePicker
          margin="normal"
          id="time-picker"
          label="Time picker"
          value={selectedDate}
          onChange={handleDateChange}
          KeyboardButtonProps={{
            'aria-label': 'change time',
          }}
        />
      </Grid>
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to convert it to a class?

Comment: just bacause i can use the advantage of the OOP